# Plotting |x| - |y| = 1?

Tags: calculus, functions

How do I know, from the equation |x| - |y| = 1, how the curve of the function looks like?
(without using software)

I have tried solving the equation for y, but I struggled to find a solution that makes sense.

Comment: Fix $y$: either it is positive and then you are looking for $x$ such that $|x|-y = 1$, or $y$ is nonpositive and you are looking for $x$ such that $|x|+y = 1$. The set of solutions will be the union of the two curves you have drawn

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Go quadrant wise
(I) x>0 & y>0 then we have line segment x-y=1,
(II) x<0 & y >0 then line segment -x-y=1
So on so forth..Also the curve is symmetric about both x and y axis. This may be called "LINEAR hyperbola". One msy recall horizontal hyperbola: x^2-y^2=1.

Comment: I think you meant $x-y=1$ for $(I)$ and $-x-y=1$ for (II)

Comment: Oh yes, thanks I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $| x | = \pm x$ is often useful and emphasises that you have two cases to consider. Here we get $|y|=|x|-1$ so we have $\pm y = |x|-1$ and this gives us two functions $y = |x|-1$ and $y=-|x|+1$. Note that  $|x|-|y|=1$ implies that $|x| \geq 1$ so the domain of these functions is $(-\infty, -1) \cup(1, \infty)$ and not all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The equation $|x|-|y| = 1$ shows that necessarily, if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $|x| \geqslant 1$. But the solution you are proposing contains the pairs $(0,\pm 1)$. Hence, there is a mistake in your reasoning. It is not true that the set of solutions to $|x|-|y|=1$ is the union of the curves $y=|x|-1$ and $y=-|x|+1$: you should add the conditions $y\geqslant 0$ and $y\leqslant 0$ respectively.

Comment: @Didier great point. It's the right functions but the domain needs to be restricted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x-y=1$, then exclude the part of the $xy$-plane to the left of the $y$-axis (exclude $x<0$). Then, reflect (mirror) the right half of the plane over $y$-axis to get $|x|-y=1$. Then exclude the part of the plane below the $x$-axis and reflect (mirror) $y>0$ over $x$-axis. We have $|x|-|y|=1$. Doing this in the other order, $|y|$ then $|x|$, gives the same result.

This is basically saying, *only* look in the quadrant $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and you have the rest of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

After tryihg these answers, see if you get this:
[image: graph]